# finding hidden field value above a checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to return the hidden input field value above a checked checkbox. As it is at the moment I am finding a value of `undefined`.

This is what I have tried.

```
var checkedTopics = document.getElementsByName("chkRelatedTopics");
for (var i = 0; i < checkedTopics.length; i++) {
    if (checkedTopics[i].checked) {
        var uniqueKeyTopic = $(this).parent().
                       find("input[name=hidTopicsDomain]").val();
        console.log(uniqueKeyTopic);
    }

}
```

this is the markup

```
{{each Items}}
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        <input type='hidden' 
                              name='hidTopicsDomain' value='${DomainObjectKey}'/>
                        <input type='checkbox' 
                                     name='chkRelatedTopics' value='${subject}'/>
                    </td>
                    <td><label id='labRelatedTopicDisplay'>${subject}</label>
                </tr>

            {{/each}}
```

How can I retrieve this hidden `input field` value?

Thanks

Comment: Use `$(this).closest("input[name=hidTopicsDomain]")` instead of `$(this).parent().find("input[name=hidTopicsDomain]")`

Comment: what's the value of `this` supposed to be?  You're not setting it in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
$(this).prev('input[name=hidTopicsDomain]').val();
});
```

or if you want to control checked and unchecked then use this:

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
   //perform something if checked
   }
   else{
   //perform something if not checked.
   }
    });
```

Comment: @Arianule check my answer it now gives u a way to do something based on checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this in the for loop, use .each() and use siblings to find the input

```
var checkedTopics = document.getElementsByName("chkRelatedTopics");
$(checkedTopics).each(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        var uniqueKeyTopic = $(this).siblings("input[name=hidTopicsDomain]").val();
        console.log(uniqueKeyTopic);
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't `if ($(this).is(':checked'))` kind of a complicated way of saying `if (this.checked)`?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much forgot about this.checked i'll edit the question, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Check below if this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep605085/28peQ/2/

```
html:
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='hidTopicsDomain' value='HiddenFieldValue1'/>
        <input type='checkbox' checked name='chkRelatedTopics' value='checkbox1'/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label id='labRelatedTopicDisplay'>label1</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='hidTopicsDomain' value='HiddenFieldValue2' />
        <input type='checkbox' checked name='chkRelatedTopics' value='checkbox2'/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label id='labRelatedTopicDisplay'>label2</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='hidTopicsDomain' value='HiddenFieldValue3'/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='chkRelatedTopics' value='checkbox3' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label id='labRelatedTopicDisplay'>label3</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='button' id='buttonclick' value='Click to Test' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>


js:

$('#buttonclick').click(function(){
    var checkedTopics = $('input[name="chkRelatedTopics"]');

    checkedTopics.each(function(){

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var uniqueKeyTopic = $(this).prev().val();
            alert(uniqueKeyTopic);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks.